# query for inner join of table 4

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I'm facing the problem of inner join of table 4
following is query  given plz see & give me solution

```
select INSURED.FNAME + ' ' + INSURED.LNAME AS MNAME
,INSURED.MEMBCODE as MEMBERCODE
,INSURED.POLICYNO AS POLICYNO
,INSURED.POLICYFRMDATE AS POLICYFROMDATE
,INSURED.POLICYTODATE AS POLICYTODATE
, MEMBERSHIP.MRKEXTNAME AS MARKETINGEXECUTIVE
,MEMBERSHIP.EMPLOYEECOUNT AS EMPLOYEECOUNT
,INSURED.CLAIMID AS CLAIMID
,POLICY.POLICYTYPE
,POLICY.COVAMTHOSPITAL as SUMINSURED
,ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATIONNAME  
from ((INSURED 
inner join MEMBERSHIP on MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPID=INSURED.MEMBERSHIPID) 
inner join POLICY on MEMBERSHIP.POLICYNAME=POLICY.POLICYNAME) 
inner join ORGANIZATION on ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATIONID=MEMBERSHIP.ORGANIZATIONID 
WHERE INSUREDID=427
```

Comment: It might also be helpful to state which database engine you're using. From the bracketing in the FROM clause, my guess is MS Access - but it's only a guess.

Comment: query execute but doesn't show any value

Comment: Is there an INSUREDID=427? Have you tried changing the inner joins to LEFT OUTER JOINS?

Comment: Yes I'm using MSaccess,Problem is when I add extra inner join of organization then query not giv me required data

Comment: yes sir insuredID is 427

Comment: Well, then it seems there is not a single membership linked to an organization for id 427.

Answer (score 0):

After making it a bit more readable there doesn't seem to be much wrong. I removed the brackets as they aren't needed.  I would also put the INNER JOINS the other way round as its normal to put them in this order.

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name

So it should look something like

```
select INSURED.FNAME + ' ' + INSURED.LNAME AS MNAME,
INSURED.MEMBCODE as MEMBERCODE,
INSURED.POLICYNO AS POLICYNO,
INSURED.POLICYFRMDATE AS POLICYFROMDATE,
INSURED.POLICYTODATE AS POLICYTODATE,
MEMBERSHIP.MRKEXTNAME AS MARKETINGEXECUTIVE,
MEMBERSHIP.EMPLOYEECOUNT AS EMPLOYEECOUNT,
INSURED.CLAIMID AS CLAIMID,
POLICY.POLICYTYPE,
POLICY.COVAMTHOSPITAL as SUMINSURED,
ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATIONNAME
FROM INSURED
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP on INSURED.MEMBERSHIPID=MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPID
INNER JOIN POLICY on POLICY.POLICYNAME=MEMBERSHIP.POLICYNAME
INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION on MEMBERSHIP.ORGANIZATIONID=ORGANIZATION.ORGANIZATIONID
WHERE INSUREDID=427
```

You need to tell us what the problem is.  Does it return results different to what you are expecting or does it fail with an error.

You should also tell us which database you are using.

Also there appears to be something odd about your table structure.  You would not normally store PolicyName in your Membership Table rather you should be linking with ID Fields of some kind rather than PolicyName Strings...Something Like

INNER JOIN POLICY on POLICY.POLICYID=MEMBERSHIP.POLICYID

You got it right for with OrganizationID and MEMBERSHIPID

In short you need to tell us more about it.

Comment: You need brackets on those joins in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: How will that help if the required answer needs a match?

Comment: @Remou - OP Only needs a match on INSURED. LEFT JOINING everything would make it easy to spot what table(s) do(es) not have its links set up correct.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the brackets around your inner join statements.

Comment: You need brackets on those joins in Access.